# Staged Donation Form in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to create a staged donation form in Bootstrap, where you use forward and backward buttons to move to another part of the same form. It would have a nice indicator at the top, denoting what step of completion you are at. Staged donation forms increases donation rates an average of 4.8%, so I would really like to have it.

I found a [tutorial online](http://www.2my4edge.com/2014/12/step-by-step-tab-style-form-validation.html) to do so and it's very nice, but it has some problems I hope someone can help me fix (code at link):
[image]

1) If placed in a column side by side with another, it glitches out when the next button is pressed, shifting the content down a row.

2) I am unable to apply the CSS min-height attribute and have it hold true after the next button is pressed. This would keep each part of the form the same height and the button at the bottom in the same place.

3) It does not include javascript for a Back button.

4) I really don't need the form validation, so it's useless bulk.

Thanks for any help you guys can give me, I know it's quite a lot of help to ask for in one question, but JS is not my specialty and it's pro bono work for a charity.

Comment: Try to narrow down your question and [create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, I do have a functional draft, would that help? Or should I delete this and start over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the back button, what you have to do is create a new button to go to the previous step and add it to the HTML for the 2nd and 3rd steps. Then you can basically duplicate the `nextBtn` functionality and reuse it for the previous button (but you can remove the input validation since it's not necessary for a previous button).

Here's the button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Back</button>
```

And the Javascript:

```
allPrevBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");

          prevStepWizard.trigger('click');
  });
```

## [Working example](http://www.bootply.com/bbzQzrj0lb)

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly and I managed to remove the form validation as well (trial and error). Now my only major issue is the column being pushed down up when placed side by side with another column. I will just use break tags to even out the height.

Comment: My CSS issues were entirely structural. Thanks for solving my problem for me!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: I will post the final site template when it's up. You saved my bacon :)